# HTML CSS - Logout button at rightmost part of navigation bar

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, uinavigationbar, navigationbar

What I've done is I placed &nbsp a lot of times but when you change the size of the window, the logout button does not stay put.How do you make the logout button stay in the rightmost portion of the navigation bar besides using the &nbsp code? Thanks

[image]

Comment: You just don't use `&nbsp;`. Use `margin` or `float`. Remove the '&nbsp;'. It's bad

Comment: can you include your html and css in your question?

Comment: Using &nbsp will always add a blank space regardless of the size of the window. If you want the logout button to stay in the right you can use float: right or marrgin to keep the position regardless of the size of the window.

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
         div.horizontal ul {
         list-style-type: none;
         margin: 0px;
         padding: 0px;
         }
         div.horizontal {
         width: 100%;
         height: 30px;
         background-color: #98BF21;
         }
         div.horizontal li {
         float: left;
         }
         div.horizontal a:link, div.horizontal a:visited {
         font-weight: bold;
         color: #FFF;
         background-color: #98BF21;
         text-align: center;
         padding: 4px;
         text-decoration: none;
         text-transform: uppercase;
         }
         div.horizontal a {
         display: block;
         width: 100px;
         }
         li.last
         {
         float:right !important;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="horizontal">
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Articles</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li class="last"><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no valid reason to add the class last on the last li element. CSS has a pseudo-class to do just that, instead last you should use :last-child, so: ul li:last-child